# Appscan source edition - SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql-injection, owasp, esapi, secure-coding

I am using Appscan source edition for Java Secure Coding. It is reporting an SQL injection in my application. The issue is that we are generating the query dynamically in code so I cannot use a prepared statement. Instead I have to us e `Esapi.encoder().encodeForSql(new OracleCodec(), query)`. AppScan does not consider this to mitigate the SQL injection issue.

```
final String s = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = " +
    Esapi.encoder().encodeForSql(new OracleCodec(), userId);            
statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);
```

This code additionally does not work for `ESAPI.encoder()`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

what you should do is

```
final String s = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?"
statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);
statement.setString(1, userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [encodeForSQL](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForSQL%28org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec,%20java.lang.String%29) recommends a `PreparedStatement` which you can still use which dynamically generated queries:

> Encode input for use in a SQL query, according to the selected codec
>   (appropriate codecs include the MySQLCodec and OracleCodec). **This
>   method is not recommended. The use of the PreparedStatement interface
>   is the preferred approach. However, if for some reason this is
>   impossible, then this method is provided as a weaker alternative.** The
>   best approach is to make sure any single-quotes are double-quoted.
>   Another possible approach is to use the {escape} syntax described in
>   the JDBC specification in section 1.5.6. However, this syntax does not
>   work with all drivers, and requires modification of all queries.

Let's check what the encoder is doing to see why your code have an injection vulnerability. The encoder calls `encodeCharacter` in the oracle codec which simply replaces single quotes with two single quotes:

```
public String encodeCharacter( char[] immune, Character c ) {
    if ( c.charValue() == '\'' )
        return "\'\'";
    return ""+c;
}
```

This only makes sense if the value is inside single quotes, which string values would be. If `id` is actually an integer and you wanted to concatenate it with the query, then you would convert it to an int type first instead of using this encoder.